# Port Forwarding

Tags: java, sockets, nat, tunneling

I have a simple requirement of a software level port forwarding/tunnelling of socket based communication.

- I have a source server and port using Sockets. This is a java program which works both in windows and linux and this is irrelevant.
- I have devices which keep sending data to this port. There may be a bi-directional communication
- I want to redirect this data to another remote server and port. So for the clients they will not have to worry about change of ip address whenever I move my app server.

Are there any tools/deamon/service programs which I can use to configure and do this?

I tried SSH, but to my understanding this needs a SSH protocol enabled server. In my case this is not applicable. I also tried using JSch but this again is an implementation of SSH in java format.

Can someone throw some pointers? Is it possible to use iptables NAT in linux?

Comment: Are you using any standard protocol or your own custom protocol ?

Comment: It is just a TCP/IP data communication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `netcat` or `socat` (it's more powerful than netcat)

An example for socat to forward port 80 using tcp4:

```
socat tcp4-listen:80,fork tcp4:{another server}:{another port}
```

and refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Port_Forwarding_or_Port_Mapping for netcat

Both are not java-related.

Comment: Wow! How did I forget this!! I have a question though! Can socat or netcat automatically reconnect if a connection is broken?

Comment: I don't know if there is a built-in option to reconnect, but it can be client's job to reconnect if anything wrong

Comment: This says "2011/12/04 15:52:25 socat[4328] E connect(3, AF=2 ipaddress:5000, 16): Address already in use". I tried the command with reuseaddr option also.

Comment: Just so that everybody is benefitted, the command I finally used "socat -d -d -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:9002,fork,reuseaddr TCP4:127.0.0.1:9000" which enables unlimited number of simultaneous connections. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a TCP/IP port forwarding utility named [portforward](http://code.google.com/p/portforward/) available in `code.google.com`. It is entirely written in Java.

Comment: Will give this a try & confirm if this would suit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running `xinetd` on your system already, it provides a simple [port forwarding mechanism](http://go.hopx.net/2009/11/xinetd-port-forwarding.html) that might be useful if you're not running IPTables already.

If you are running IPTables, Server Fault has an excellent, [short question with a very similar goal](https://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables). Though I find it a bit terse [more detailed documentation is available](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//NAT-HOWTO.txt).